# Using AForge.Video.DirectShow with ZXing.Net

Tags: barcode, zxing, directshow, aforge

Can anyone share code with optimal AForge.Video settings for ZXing.Net? I am feeding webcam images into ZXing using AForge.Video.DirectShow.

Just to be clear, I hold a printed barcode in front of my webcam, and let AForge capture it.

My code below results in fuzzy images that cannot be decoded by ZXing. In order to make it work, I must print barcodes with very large fonts. This is not practical.

The code below works, but requires really big barcodes. I'm hoping there are better settings that improve the image quality for ZXing, such as optimal resolution, contrast, brightness, bits-per-pixel, etc.

```
using AForge;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using ZXing;

FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
videoSource.Start();
```

Images look like this (before and after):

[image: fuzzy barcode image]

Comment: Looks like some problems with the focus. Perhaps you should try to play with the focus setting: videoSource.SetCameraProperty(
                CameraControlProperty.Focus,
                focusValue,
                CameraControlFlags.Auto);

Comment: That didn't work. Does anyone have the correct settings for ZXing?